# Lenovo wireless issue

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

When I turn on my Lenovo G550, the wireless card's led is not flashing and I cannot scan for wireless networks. When I go to the Additional Drivers to install the missing driver I indeed find my driver. When I click on Activate though it starts loading and says:

```
An error occured" refer to: /var/log/jockey.log"
```

The driver is NOT activated it seems.
The output of jockey is:

```
2014-03-06 17:41:36,838 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2014-03-06 17:41:36,952 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2014-03-06 17:41:36,982 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2014-03-06 17:41:37,098 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2014-03-06 17:41:37,841 DEBUG: Shutting down
```

Even though I get that error message I get wireless internet after that, but when I boot up again I have to follow the same procedure.